# Parse a table with BeautifulSoup, Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://rocketreach.co/horizon-blue-cross-blue-shield-of-new-jersey-email-format_b5c604a3f42e0c54
This is the link I'm trying to get the information out of. I need to extract the formats that's in the table "first '_' last" "first_initial last" and so on. If not all of them, then at least the top most format.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def search_on_google(key_word, driver):
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    searchBoard = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    searchBoard.send_keys(key_word + " Rocketreach.co")
    searchBoard.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    searchBoard.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cite").click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('meta'):
        content = link.get('content')
        print(content)
```

Edit:

```
    for i in range(1):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cite").click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1][not(contains(text(), 'Lorem ipsum...'))]")))

    table_id = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
    rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    for row in rows:
        tds = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        top_format.append(tds[0].text)
        domain.append(tds[1].text)
        print(top_format)
        print(domain)
        break

    return top_format
```

Comment: What format are you talking about? What do you need to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one table on this page to print all the information you can simply do
the following to print all the information. It is also not in any iframes.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1][not(contains(text(), 'Lorem ipsum...'))]")))
table_id = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for td in tds:
       one_urls.append(td.text)
print(one_urls)
```

You could do a check before the print or you could do a range.

```
if tds[0] =='':
```

I'd also suggest a wait prior to finding the table since your clicking and loading a new page prior to getting the table.

```
table_id= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")))
```

Import these

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: even after waiting to find the table it still prints ['Lorem ipsum...', 'Lorem ipsum...', 'Lorem ipsum...', 'Lorem ipsum...', 'Lorem ipsum...',] how do i overcome this

Comment: Add some implicit_waits it seems to take a while to load the data.

Comment: Or wait till //table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()="first '_' last" becomes visible.

Comment: where would I write that? and what's the exact syntax? I'm sorry I'm a little confused

Comment: After you driver.get() the page takes a while to load the right data.

Comment: Still not working. I've edited the question so you can see the edited code. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or test it out yourself? :) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Works well. 2 follow-up questions:
1) How do I make it read only the first row? So for example: ["first '.' last", 'jane.doe@gs.com', '92.9%'] should become [first.last@gs.com]

2) Sometimes Rocketreach doesn't have a company's email format. So, how would I write an If-else condition which says "if there's no email format/table, continue to next cell in excel"

Comment: Done. Where would I break? And what about reading just the first row and putting it in the format [first.last@gs.com]?

Comment: You can access  tds[0] or tds[1] to pull their values from. If you don't want to pull them one by one.

Comment: it keeps says that tds[0] is not iterable. Could you show me where exactly to put it?  I'm trying to get it in a format of [first.last@gs.com]

Comment: for td in tds: take this out and use one_urls.append(tds[0].text).

Comment: ok perfect so I'm getting ["first '.' last", 'jane.doe@dxc.com']. How do I combine this as ["first.last@dxc.com"]  .. with no apostrophe around the dot.

Comment: any idea on what I should do?

Comment: Remove ' from string and substring the second from the index of @.

Comment: Hey so, I figured everything out but I have one last question:
sometimes the website doesn't have a table for small companies. So I want to write a if condition where it says that "if table is not found then continue to next one" How do I write that?

Comment: table_wait.size should return 1 if found 0 otherwise.